# WebResourceLoadDelegate in OSX 10.11

Tags: webkit, osx-elcapitan

WebResourceLoadDelegate in OSX 10.11 docs is "Available in OS X v10.2 through OS X v10.10.3" . What  does it means ?

Comment: It's a protocol. Doc hasn't been updated. As long as you can access it by CMD+SHIFT+O "Webresource" you can use it.

Comment: In Docs there is a red strikethrough over protocol's methods. Also    "Available in..."  is in red color.

Comment: You are right. It's been removed. This means if you compile with 10.11 SDK you cannot use it. If you link with 10.10 or earlier you are free to use it. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_11/Objective-C/WebKit.html

Comment: SpecialPictureProtocol sample code (from Docs) is using WebResourceLoadDelegate.  Built with 10.11 SDK, still running.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `WebResourceLoadDelegate` *informal* protocol has been removed in OS X 10.11. Instead, the new `WebResourceLoadDelegate` *formal* protocol has been introduced at the same time (or maybe earlier, I'm not sure) to provide the same API. Though the new protocol has yet to be documented, you can use it freely.